Can't communicate device with his RS323 to 2 pins uart of GPIO
I have a a microbench device, it has his RS232 port.

but I just can read data from this microbench device with this cable:

The microbench device have tx pin with -9V. How can I comunícate microbench device with raspberry using using uart ports GPIO 14 and GPIO 15?

This question makes no sense. One uses USB the other GPIO pins! What is connected to what?

I also suggest you use a spell checker, I am having to guess what you are trying to say.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you do not want to use a USB to Serial cable like you've shown in your question but want to connect directly to the UART pins, you need a level converter that translates the RS232 voltage levels output by your Microbench device to TTL levels that can be safely used by the Raspberry Pi. You could use a module based on the MAX3232 (for example). Why is your question tagged with "python"?

You will need an RS232 to TTL converter module.

I will prove an RS232 to TTL, thanks a lot
